# Many to Many Self Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, many-to-many, data-annotations

An user can manage many company. And an user can have an active company at a time from list of many-company. How I can achieve this?

My current model is :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
    }
}
public class Company
{
    public int Id

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
}
```

If I add another anotation :

```
public class User
{
    public int CompanyId

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

This model wont referenced to many-to-many table which `UserCompany` table.

How I can achieve this? Or is there another approach for this case?

[image]

Now I'm thinking about make manual many-to-many relationship model and add another `ActiveCompany` field referenced from custom many-to-many relationship. Is this good approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do this by using the fluent api and overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in your `DbContext`, but I don't have an example to hand.

However you might just find it easier to add another property for your user

```
public int ActiveCompanyId { get; set; }
```

There are a lot of variables like if you are using lazy loading, how many companies / users there are, what your patterns of data access are, which may determine your best overall approach. If your `Companies` property is usually or always populated then you could create a `get` only property that is not mapped:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public int ActiveCompanyId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Company ActiveCompany
    {
        get
        {
          return this.Companys == null ? null :
                      Companies.Where(x => x.Id == this.Active.CompanyId)
                               .SingleOrDefault;
        }
    }

    public User()
    {
       this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
    }
}
```

Comment: HI there, Im thinking about making this ActiveCompanyId as foreign key to `CompanyId` in many-to-many relationship, in case the `ActiveCompanyId` is not in many-to-many table. I think this model will allow any `ActiveCompanyId` in Companies even not in many-to-many table. Is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: Try it and see - don't know off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this mapping :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Users)
        .WithMany(u => u.Comapnies)
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("CompanyId");
            x.MapRightKey("UserId");
            x.ToTable("UserCompany");
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.Company)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```